# Memory Leaking, I can't seem to find why

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, heap-memory

So I am writing a program for managing a heap data structure. I make two dynamic memory allocations and (I think) I free them correctly when im wrapping things up.

```
#include "heapFunctions.h"
#include "util.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Function Prototypes
static element* getArray(int*);

int main(void){
int result=0;
int i,v;
heap myHeap;
myHeap.H = NULL;
int arrayLength;
element* myArray = NULL;
char menuSelection = nextCommand(&i,&v);        //get selection from user
while(!(menuSelection == 'S' || menuSelection == 's')){
    switch(menuSelection){
        case 'c':
        case 'C':
            if(myHeap.H == NULL)
                myHeap = initialize(i);         //initialize heap and identify any errors
            else{
                free(myHeap.H);
                myHeap=initialize(i);
            }
            if(myHeap.H != NULL)
                printf("Command Entered %c. Heap Initialized with capacity %d\n", menuSelection, i);
            else
                printf("Command Entered %c. Heap space not allocated\n", menuSelection);
            break;
        case 'r':
        case 'R':
            if(myArray == NULL)
                myArray = getArray(&arrayLength);               //populate array from text file
            else{
                free(myArray);
                myArray = getArray(&arrayLength);
            }
            result=buildHeap(&myHeap, myArray, arrayLength);        //build heap with array
            if(result==1)
                printf("Command Entered %c. Heap was built with size %d\n", menuSelection, arrayLength);
            else if (result == -1)
                printf("Command Entered %c. Heap build was unsuccesful\n", menuSelection);
            else if (result == -2)
                printf("Command Entered %c. Heap capacity can't accomodate array\n", menuSelection);
            break;
        case 'w':
        case 'W':
            printf("Command Entered %c. Printing Heap\n", menuSelection);
            printHeap(&myHeap);                 //print contents of heap
            break;
        case 'i':
        case 'I':
            result = insert(&myHeap, i);            //insert new key i into heap
            if (result == 1)
                printf("Command Entered %c. Heap insert with key %d was succesful\n", menuSelection, i);
            else
                printf("Command Entered %c. Heap insert was unsuccesful\n", menuSelection);
            break;
        case 'd':
        case 'D':
            result = deleteMax(&myHeap);        //extract max value from heap
            if (result > 0)
                printf("Command Entered %c. Deletion of max heap value %d was succesful\n", menuSelection, result);
            break;
        case 'k':
        case 'K':
            result = increaseKey(&myHeap, i, v);            //increase key at index i to v
            if(result == 1)
                printf("Command Entered %c. Key was succesfully increased to %d at index %d\n", menuSelection, v, i);
            else if(result == -1)
                printf("Command Entered %c. Key increase failed, %d not a valid index\n", menuSelection, i);
            else if (result == -2)
                printf("Command Entered %c. Key increase failed, %d is not larger than current key\n", menuSelection, v);
            else if (result == -3)
                printf("Command Entered %c. Key increase failed, Index starts at 1!", menuSelection);
    }
    menuSelection = nextCommand(&i,&v); 
}
printf("You have entered command %c and stopped the program.\n", menuSelection);

//free resources
free(myArray);
free(myHeap.H);
return 1;
}

//get array from text file for heap
static element* getArray(int *Length){
    element *arrayKey;          //declare pointer for new array
    int arrayLength=0;
    char inputBuffer[10];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("HEAPinput.txt","r");            //open text file
    if (fp == NULL){                    /*check to make sure file was opened*/
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open input file!!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(fgets(inputBuffer, sizeof(inputBuffer), fp) != NULL){        //get line of text
        sscanf(inputBuffer, "%d", &arrayLength);                //parse line for number of inputs
    }

    if(arrayLength < 1){                //error if array length is invalid
        printf("Invalid Array Length\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    arrayKey = (element *) malloc(sizeof(element)*arrayLength);     //dynamically allocate memory for values
    if(arrayKey == NULL){
        printf("Memory for array not allocated\n");
         exit(1);
    }   
    int count;

    for (count =0; count < arrayLength; count++){               //populate array with input from file
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &arrayKey[count].key);
    }

    *Length = arrayLength;  
    fclose(fp);                                             //close file
    return arrayKey;                        //return array      
}


//initialize new heap with size 0 and designated capacity
heap initialize(int capacity){
    heap myHeap;
    myHeap.size = 0;
    myHeap.capacity = capacity;
    myHeap.H = (element*) malloc(sizeof(element)*capacity);         //dynamically allocate memory blocks for heap with designated capacity
    return myHeap;
}

//copy contents of heap into H element,
int buildHeap(heap *myHeap, element * myArray, int arrayLength){
    if(arrayLength > myHeap->capacity)      //error if capacity is to small
        return -2;
    if(myHeap->H == NULL)
        return -3;
    if(memcpy(myHeap->H, myArray, sizeof(element)*arrayLength) == NULL)     //error if memory not allocated properly
        return -1;

    myHeap->size=arrayLength;               //set size to arrayLength

    int count=0;
    for(count=(arrayLength/2); count >= 0; count--){            //buildHeap
        heapify(myHeap, count);
    }
    return 1;

}
```

Im not really sure how this works, i tried just posting the pieces of code i thought were necesarry. I only dynamically allocate memory in two spots and I thought I freed them properly before I leave main. I don't see where else I could be leaking.

I used valgrind and got the errors

```
 LEAK SUMMARY:
 ==4042==    definitely lost: 13,546 bytes in 70 blocks
 ==4042==    indirectly lost: 53 bytes in 5 blocks
 ==4042==      possibly lost: 29 bytes in 2 blocks
 ==4042==    still reachable: 33,958 bytes in 53 blocks
```

I also had it print the whole trace (with debugging symbols) but all the outputs were pretty much the same (repeats the following for most blocks). I tried compiling with gcc + g++ with valgrind with the -g flag and fulltrace but i still just get ??? for the output after mem location.

```
==5804== 3 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 2 of 97
==5804==    at 0x4C2C73C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==5804==    by 0x440137: ??? (in /usr/bin/g++-4.7)
==5804==    by 0x43CDEB: ??? (in /usr/bin/g++-4.7)
==5804==    by 0x414C80: ??? (in /usr/bin/g++-4.7)
==5804==    by 0x41592F: ??? (in /usr/bin/g++-4.7)
==5804==    by 0x40296E: ??? (in /usr/bin/g++-4.7)
==5804==    by 0x4E5576C: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)


349 (320 direct, 29 indirect) bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record          73 of 96
==4098==  at 0x4C2C92E: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:662)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction, as to why I am leaking memory.

Comment: valgrind is there to help you. Compile your code with `-g` to include debugging symbols and then run valgrind with `--leak-check=full`. Generally the man page of valgrind has a lot more information.

Comment: Don't do this: `&(*(arrayKey + count)).key` Do this: `&arrayKey[count].key`

Comment: I fixed that (although, out of curiosity why should I need to change that, aren't they identical, besides readibility?). And I did leakcheck full with -g flag, didn't provide much new information as to where I might be leaking. I had only posted a fragment of the trace because its so long, most of them are the same output just different blocks and different leak amount.

Comment: If you still have these `???` in the valgrind trace, you didn't compile the code in question with `-g`. These are supposed to give you the trace of function from which you called `malloc`.

Comment: Then also don't compile C code with g++. These are two different languages. As an extra bonus you may then take of the casts before `malloc`.

Comment: In the code you are showing use there no allocation of 3 bytes. The leak probably isn't in the code you are showing us. Voting to close.

Comment: Note: For future work, suggest you do not use `fgets()` with `fscanf()` on the same FILE.  Your use of them here is OK, but in general, their combined use is problematic on how end-of-lines are handled.

Comment: After `arrayKey = malloc(sizeof(element)*arrayLength)`, the fields, if any, other than `.key` are not initialize.  Suggest explicitly initializing each field.  Further, test the result of `fscanf(fp, "%d", &arrayKey[count].key)`.

Comment: `if(memcpy(myHeap->H, myArray, sizeof(element)*arrayLength) == NULL)` is _not_ good.  Should `myHeap->H` be NULL, you have all ready attempted to write to NULL.  Instead `if (myHeap->H == NULL) { error } else memcpy(myHeap->H, ...)`

Comment: `for(count=(arrayLength/2); count >= 0; count--) heapify(myHeap, count)` looks like a potential issue as you eventually call `heapify()` with a count of 0.  Maybe `for(count=(arrayLength/2); count > 0; count--)`?

Comment: key is the only field in element so that shouldnt be a problem. Noted on the fscan + gets, i will avoid that in the future. Ill fix the memcpy, that could definitely be a problem so thanks. Calling heapify for count 0 shouldnt be a problem. @Jens, i recompiled it with gcc and made sure i used the -g flag. The result was the same with the ???. Am i missing something?

Comment: The way it is written, it appears as if `insert` would have to allocate memory (e.g., realloc) to make room for the new key.  Perhaps that a leak is in that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one leak:

```
case 'R':
    myArray = getArray(&arrayLength);               //populate array from text file
```

I'm not sure how many times you execute the 'R' menu selection but `myArray` is never freed within the while loop. Each time this selection is executed you leak the memory `myArray` was previously pointing too. After you exit the while loop you are only freeing the last memory location that was allocated.

Likewise with 'C':

```
case 'C':
    myHeap = initialize(i);         //initialize heap and identify any errors
```

If you execute this more than one time, you leak the memory that `myHeap` was previously pointing to. After exiting the loop you only free the last memory location allocated to `myHeap.H`.

**Update:**

With your latest update, you now need to initialize your variables. Because they live on the stack they likely contain garbage. For instance, the first time you check `myArray == NULL` it will likely return false causing you to attempt to free memory that hasn't been allocated.

```
heap myHeap;
myHeap.H = NULL;

element* myArray = NULL;
```

Comment: I had tried some logic to free them before each call if they were already allocated. I got the same trace unfortunately. I went ahead and implemented those changes and updated the code in my post, but it is still leaking.

Comment: First, thanks for the response! I added that and updated my code and I still have the same leakage :/

Comment: If you've implemented the fixes shown here and followed the advice in the comments above and you still have a leak, then the problem lies in some other part of the code. We'd need to see the code for `printHeap`, `insert`, `deleteMax`, `increaseKey` and possibly even `nextCommand`.

Comment: Turns out I was accidentally attaching valgrind to gcc because I was trying to one line it. But you pointed out the leaks that were there so thanks!